# Rhino.Licensing.LicenseExpired is crashing visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have VS 2010 crashing with the following problem signature:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 10.0.40219.1
  Problem Signature 03: 4d5f2a73
  Problem Signature 04: Rhino.Licensing
  Problem Signature 05: 0.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 52272042
  Problem Signature 07: 40
  Problem Signature 08: 9c
  Problem Signature 09: Rhino.Licensing.LicenseExpired
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033

Saw the Rhino-License.txt in SmartBear folder which is from SoapUI. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue today. It appears that the Rhino Licensing library was included in one of my plugins or libraries. By removing the plugin/extension I was able to stop the error.

**Here is how I removed the add-ins and extensions:**

1. Tools> Add-In Manager: Removed All Add Ins ("Chirpy" and "Git
   Extensions")
2. Tools> Extension Manager: Removed All Extensions except Nu-Get
   Package Manager.

**Conclusion:**
This stopped the crashes. I am not certain, but I would guess that one of these plugins is using the Rhino Licensing library and for whatever reason the license authentication is failing causing the crashes.

Try removing some add ins if you can to see it that helps. **I should have removed them one at a time until I found the faulty app, but I foolishly removed several and now I can not be sure which was guilty.**

Comment: In my case it's NUnit 3.0 Test Adapter for Visual Studio. My VS instance stops crashing after I have this extension upgraded to the latest version.